# jQuery to CSS pop up banner/footer [compatability]

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, banner

I am currently testing a jQuery banner which only shows up when the user starts with scrolling down (currently < 350 ).

I'd like to implement a CSS3 version of this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 350) {
            $("#carriage-promo").slideUp();
        } else {
            $("#carriage-promo").slideDown();
        }
    });
</script>
```

It's been advised I use a detect function, then CSS3 ease transition.  But I'm new to CSS3 and unsure how I can do this.

The CSS I'm using for the `<div>` at the minute is:

```css
#carriage-promo {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:40px;
    width:964px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;

    /* The following styles are optional */

    padding: 0px;
    background: #000000;
    border-top: 0px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To summarize, what I have works fine.  However, it's been suggested that I re-create what I'm doing above, but with CSS3 for compatibility reasons, i.e., have CSS3 *and* jQuery.

Any suggestions/examples I can look at?

Comment: confused what your question is..........

Comment: I'd like an alternative method for displaying a banner on scroll down, similar to how I've done it but using CSS3 rather than jQuery.

Sorry if I've not explained myself very well!

Comment: I not entirely sure you will be able to do this by eliminating js. Chech these sites http://www.w3schools.com/css3/ and http://css3generator.com/. You should be able to do slideUp and down, but detecting the height of the browser, I dont know.

Comment: It's alright I've managed to do it.  I used feature detection and a show/hide div.